# Which of Rose Quartz's powers were generic?

Tags: steven-universe

As we now know, Rose Quartz was

> Pink Diamond.

As such, she most certainly had powers that a regular or average Rose Quartz would not have had (actual Rose Quartzes definitely exist, we've seen them for instance bubbled on Homeworld).

We've seen that she had a variety of powers, beyond those of most Gems: protective, such her shield and  her protective bubbles; healing tears (or saliva in Steven's case), some form of resurrection; astral projection, dream walking, and associated possession; other biological talents such as plant control and a much better grasp of shape-shifting than other Gems; and even the ability to create Gem shards.

Has there been anything to suggest which of Rose Quartz's numerous powers were powers that a normal Quartz would have, and which were due to her...particular character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recall a single Rose Quartz appearing in non-bubbled form (maybe some silhouettes one time when a false backstory was narrated about how Rose first started to rebel) anywhere in the series.  We did see an apparently large congregation of "pink" gems on Steven's latest arrival, but I didn't see enough detail to even know if they were Rose Quartzes or not (we have seen several gems have different hues, though, such as Pearls). And no abilities were on display either way.  But possibly we will see some in upcoming episodes.

We have been told that in general quartzes are supposed to be bulky warrior types. We also know that abilities and weapons can vary at least slightly within a given type of gem: the Ruby that's part of Garnet manifests a gauntlet for a weapon (much like Garnet herself); while we see a different Ruby manifest, and try to attack Steven with, a chisel.

[image: Ruby from Garnet using a gauntlet]
[image: A Ruby using a chisel]

> We have also seen Blue and Yellow Diamond exhibit powers akin to what we've seen Steven use: an ability to heal other gems, as well as apparent psychic and astral abilities.

Otherwise it's hard to say at this point which powers might have been considered relatively "normal" for a Rose Quartz to have.  But I would hazard a guess that her size,  shield, and general willingness to fight on the front line are reasonably "Rose Quartz"-like; that the protective bubbles are kind of borderline; and the rest are particular to her exceptional origins.

Comment: That makes me wonder whether Pink Diamond made Rose Quartzes "in her image" as it were. Their gemstones are strikingly similar.